# Rails Job Doesn't Proceed after rails jobs:work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, jobs

I have a job in my rails app which I was running it before like a charm with this command:

```
rails jobs:work
```

but it doesn't proceed any longer.I killed the processes and tried a lot of solutions but nothing happened! What I guess is that this job has generated a queue so that it can not be running any more! Could you please help me? 
Thanks in advance.
It stops in this situation :

```
bundle exec rake jobs:work
[Worker(host:afsane pid:7517)] Starting job worker
```

and my job :

```
class LdapSyncJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default
  require 'pp'
  def perform
   ....
  end
end
```

**FYI**

```
ps aux | grep rails

afsane    7675  0.0  0.0  15764   968 pts/5    S+   15:24   0:00 grep --color=auto rails
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `bundle exec rake jobs:workoff`

This will start a job worker and exit when all available jobs are complete.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: this is the result : bundle exec rake jobs:workoff
[Worker(host:afsane pid:2839)] Starting job worker
[Worker(host:afsane pid:2839)] No more jobs available. Exiting

Comment: It clearly states that you have no jobs in queue to run. 

Check your application.rb to see your active job adapter. If its delayed_job then just log on to your console and run Delayed::Job.all to see if you have any pending jobs(there might be failed jobs). if you are using the default sidekiq then go through this to see if you have any jobs in queue.

Comment: There is no config for delayed job in my application.rb. it means Its the default.how can i see my jobs in queue ?

Comment: Refer this https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API 

Also if my answer helped you then please upvote or mark as correct. I could really use some points! Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved! You may laugh but I was commented the parts I was calling the job ! Thank you for putting your time on this:)